# How to define a class like ActiveSupport::StringInquirer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

Define a class which when initialized with a string e.g. 'abc' will return true if the method 'abc?' is called on it. Any other method with a trailing '?' will return false. All other methods which doesn't have a trailing '?' will raise `NoMethodError`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `method_missing` to respond to messages for which there is no method.

In `method_missing` we can check the method name and if it ends in a `?` check if it minus the `?` is equal to the string (`self`).

When using `method_missing` it is custom to also define `respond_to?`.

```
class StringInquirer < String
  private

  def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
    if method_name.to_s.end_with?('?')
      self == method_name.to_s.delete('?')
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def respond_to?(method_name, include_private = false)
    method_name.to_s.ends_with('?') || super
  end
end

name = StringInquirer.new('sally')
name.sally? # => true
```

Note this is case sensitive.

```
name.Sally? # => false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class NewStrInq < String
  def initialize(val)
    self.class.send(:define_method, "#{val}?") do
      true
    end
  end
  def method_missing(method)
    method.to_s[-1] == '?' ? false : (raise NoMethodError)
  end
end
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question it does not provide guidance on why it answers the question.  Please include information about what you're doing and why it works.

Comment: You are defining the the method on the class, so all instances will have the method defined. `NewStrInq.new('abc'); NewStrInq.new('abcc').abc? # => true`. You want to define the method on the singleton (aka ghost) class if you want to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
class StringInquirer < String
  def initialize(str)
    define_singleton_method(str + '?') { true }
    super(str)
  end
end

name = StringInquirer.new('sally')
name.sally? # => true
name.kim? # => NoMethodError
name.nil? # => false
```

By raising `NoMethodError` for *all* methods ending in a question mark you will loose `nil?` etc.